# How to hide the namespace <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> in webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Whenever I am try to browse, I want to hide the default namespace

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't (and you can't) *hide* namespace for a web service however you should (must!) change it to something meaningful that uniquely identify it on the web:

```
[WebService(Namespace="http://awesomecompany.com/services/")]
public class AwesomeWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService  {
}
```

From MSDN:

> Identify your XML Web service with a namespace that you control. For example, you can use the Internet domain name of your company as part of the namespace. Many XML Web service namespaces look similar to URLs, however, namespaces do not have to point to actual resources on the Web. (XML Web service namespaces are URIs.)
>
> Each XML Web service must have a unique namespace for client applications to distinguish the Web service from other services on the Web. For XML Web services that are under development, “http://tempuri.org" is available. However, use a more permanent namespace for published XML Web services.

See also [Namespaces in XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) for additional information about namespaces.